# why arrays of primitive types are not considered as objects

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, primitive-types

I know that arrays in java extends Objects,So why passing them as params doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}); // 1
    foo(new int[]{1,2,3});   //2
}

static void foo(Object... params) {
    System.out.println(params[0]);
}
```

moreover,why it doesn't treat the array as a single parameter (line 1)

Output from running the above is:

```
1
[I@3e25a5
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: it doesn't print the value of 1 (line 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java every function with (X... ) signature takes an array of X as parameter.

In your first example you get warning that you're passing the array of Integers as vararg Object without a cast. Java is clever enough to thing that you probably wanted to pass it as Object[] instead of a single Object. If you add a cast to Object[] the warning disappears.

In the second example the array is pàssed as only THE FIRST vararg, as every array is an object. It can't be passed as an array of object, because it's an array of primitives.

Arrays of any type are objects as you can verify running this snippet of code

```
public class Test{
    public static void test(Object a) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] i = {1,2,3,4};
        test(i);
    }
}
```

It prints "ok", which means that int[] is an Object.
~

Comment: but what about auto-boxing,why it doesn't box them into objects?

Comment: @sleimanjneidi - because that's not the way that autoboxing works.  Autoboxing will convert `int` to `Integer`, but it won't convert `int[]` to `Integer[]`.  Why?  Because it would result in more problems than it solves!

Answer (score 3):

I just tried your code, and I get:

```
1
[I@71f6f0bf
```

The thing is, your method takes an array of `Object` by varargs. So, for the first call, `params` is an array of 3 elements containing each individual `Integer`. However, `int`s are not `Object`s (`int`'s Wrapper class, `Integer`, is, but `int` isn't), so for the second call, `params` is an array of a single element containing the actual array object. That gibberish above is the output of an array's `toString()` method.

If you would have replace the varargs call with a `Object[]`, the second call would not have compiled, because an `int[]` is not a `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Object... interprets an array as a list of arguments, not as a single object.
Why not use a Set as a container instead?